# Visual Studio 2010 getting stuck during installation

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, frameworks

I had installed Visual Studio 2012 on my machine but due to some project requirements, i need to install VS 2010, i have uninstalled 2012 but i am not able to install 2010 on my machine, setup is installing some earlier components but sticking (not showing anything on the progress bar) on "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate" component.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: BTW, you didn't need to uninstall VS2012. All versions of Visual Studio can be installed side-by-side.

Comment: So what could be the reason of sticking intallation

Comment: The reason would be "some other reason"

Comment: It is not showing any error, setup installed framework 4.0 successfully but not installing VS 2010